# merge 2 pom.xml into a single xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, pom.xml

I have two pom.xml files. I need to merge them together on the basis of dependency tag with the help of xslt or any other method. I want all the dependencies present in both the xml files in my single merged xml along with the properties tag. Please have a look at these example files..

pom1.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  

  <groupId>com.javatpoint.application1</groupId>  
  <artifactId>my-application1</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0</version>  
  <packaging>jar</packaging>  

  <name>Maven Quick Start Archetype</name>  
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
             </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependency>
</project>
```

pom2.xml:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.version>1.5.8.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

output file that i want:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.version>1.5.8.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
             </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```